# How can I return an image as the output of a google sheet custom function?

Tags: google-sheets, custom-function

I have a custom function in a google sheet. How can I return an image instead of normal data(for example number) as the output of this custom function ?

In fact I am going to read this image from image-charts.com site, which means that image-charts.com creates this image for us and gives us its url, and I actually want to be able to use this image that was created in a Google Sheet cell.

Can google sheet custom functions support image as the return value of the function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give a bit more information on how you are making that requests? Is it calling a function via a button? A trigger? Calling the function in a formula? Depending on where you are doing it, you'll have different permissions and may/may not be possible to add an image.

Comment: Sure, there is no button and no trigger. It is only a function which is called in a formula. The script is executed and the output of that script is a link to an image (ie the link contains an image) and I want to display that image inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Found an answer to what you actually wanted. There is `IMAGE` ([see reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en)), a function that adds an URL as an image into a cell (didn't know it existed). So you could do something like:

```
=IMAGE(GETCHARTURL(...))
```

### Original workaround

<s>You cannot add an image in a cell.</s> You cannot show an image as the result of a formula either. <s>The best</s> What you can do is having a button that calls a Google Apps Script function that adds the images on top of the cells using `Sheet.insertImage` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row)).

I've made this little script that automatically adds the image on top of the cells that have the value `img+` followed by the image url (eg. `img+https://example.com/image.png`):

```js
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 100 // Image height in pixels
function sameRange(a, b) {
  return a.getGridId() === b.getGridId()
    && a.getA1Notation() === b.getA1Notation()
}
function addImages() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const toChange = sheet
    .createTextFinder(/^img\+https?:\/\//.source)
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .findAll()

  // Remove old image(s)
  for (let img of sheet.getImages()) {
    const range = img.getAnchorCell()
    if (toChange.some(r => sameRange(r, range))) {
      img.remove()
    }
  }

  // Create new ones
  for (let range of toChange) {
    const url = range.getValue().toString().split(/\+(.*)$/, 2)[1]
    const image = range.getSheet()
      .insertImage(url, range.getColumn(), range.getRow(), 0, 0)
    
    image.setAltTextTitle("Chart")

    const w = image.getWidth()
    const h = image.getHeight()
    image.setWidth(IMAGE_HEIGHT*w/h) // Keep aspect ratio
    image.setHeight(IMAGE_HEIGHT)
  }
}
```

Then simply make a new button (a drawing with text) and set `addImages` as the assigned script.

I don't know your exact use case so you will probably need to modify the script to better fit your needs.

### References

- [IMAGE function (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en)
- [Sheet.insertImage(url, column, row, offsetX, offsetY) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row,-offsetx,-offsety)
- [Class OverGridImage (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image)
- [Sheet.createTextFinder(findText) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [Class Range (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)